# How to add two different table column as reference in one field ( column ) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

How to add two different table column as reference in one field ( column ) in PostgreSQL

below my psql query:

```
create table salary (
  "id"  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "user_id" VARCHAR REFERENCES user_management(user_id) REFERENCES driver_management(user_id),
   "basic_pay" INT,
  "pay_group" VARCHAR,
  "pay_method" Pay_Method,
  "pay_cycle"  Pay_Cycle,
  "bank_name" VARCHAR,
  "account_number" numeric(26),
  "lmts" timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

I face this Error:
[image]

#### case:

- I my case, I have 3 table, "salary", "user_management", "driver_management"
- "user_management" and "driver_management" both table have column "user_id"
- "user_id" in these two separate tables should use only one column "salary" > "user_id" as reference.

WHAT I AM EXPECT:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign key constraints involving multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065212/foreign-key-constraints-involving-multiple-tables)

Comment: What exactly do you want to add? Please add the _other_ table's definition and tell us what exactly you want to achieve. To me, "add two columns as reference in one field" makes no sense. Do you want to put two "separated" values into a single column?

Comment: @sunder sir, see the pic

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name help me sir

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag? Are you looking for a DDL statement that works for Postgres _and_ MySQL? Why the `orm` tag? Are you looking for a solution in your obfuscation layer rather than a SQL script?

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name "orm" & "mysql" tag  maybe help me reach out this consent. because if anyone know orm, maybe also know sql query! also maybe they can face this case, like me